# Amazon SES: Unable to send mail for verified email address, if region is changed

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm integrating Amazon SES SDK in my iOS app. I have recently observed that, I'm unable to send mails from a verified email address. if I switch to US_WEST_2 region. The problem seem to be with iOS SDK, as I'm able to send mail from Amazon Console using same mail address.

Error Message:
exception={SESMessageRejectedException { RequestId:70ed2e9e-dc16-11e3-89ca-956987a01a60, ErrorCode:MessageRejected, Message:Email address is not verified. }}, errorCode=MessageRejected}

Code:
 SESManager class:

```
    SESSendEmailRequest *ser = [[SESSendEmailRequest alloc] init] ;

    ser.source      = strSenderMailAddress;
    ser.destination = destination;
    ser.message     = message;

    SESSendEmailResponse *response = [[AmazonClientManager ses] sendEmail:ser];
```

AmazonClientManager:

```
+(AmazonSESClient *)ses
{
    [AmazonClientManager validateCredentials];
    return ses;
}

+(void)validateCredentials
{
    if ([AmazonClientManager hasCredentials]) {

            [AmazonClientManager clearCredentials];

            ses = [[AmazonSESClient alloc] initWithAccessKey:[Lockbox stringForKey:kLockboxAmazonAccessKey] withSecretKey:[Lockbox stringForKey:kLockboxAmazonSecretKey]];

 ses.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints sesEndpoint:@"https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"];

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippet for instantiating an SES client and sending an email so that I can repro the issue?

Comment: Hi Yosuke, Please check code snippet. As per guideline, I have verified a new email address for US_WEST_2 region, but I'm unable to send mail using my app with that email address. But, It's working fine if, I try send mail from Amazon console using the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are seeing is by design.

The regions are independent systems, like much of AWS.

> **“**You must verify each sender’s email address separately for each region you want to use.**”**
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html</sup>

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have verified a new email address for US_WEST_2 region, but still I'm not able to send mail with that address using iOS SDK. I'm able to send mail from Amazon Console by selecting US_WEST_2 region & using same email address verified for that region.

Comment: I might have misinterpreted your question.  At one time, SES only had one region, us-east-1. Is your SDK version current, or is it possible that it contains an implicit assumption of only one possible region?  I assume you have this under control but that's the only remaining guess I have.

Answer (score 0):

`sesEndpoint:` takes an `AmazonRegion`, which is defined as follows:

```
typedef enum
{
    US_EAST_1      = 0,
    US_WEST_1      = 1,
    EU_WEST_1      = 2,
    AP_SOUTHEAST_1 = 3,
    AP_NORTHEAST_1 = 4,
    US_WEST_2      = 5,
    SA_EAST_1      = 6,
    AP_SOUTHEAST_2 = 7
} AmazonRegion;
```

You need to change this line:

```
ses.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints sesEndpoint:@"https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"];
```

to this:

```
ses.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints sesEndpoint:US_WEST_2];
```

When you pass an invalid region, it will default to the US East 1 region. That's why you are getting the exception.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Yosuke. Sorry for late reply. I have tried with US_WEST_2 option also, but its not working. Also, I have tried by changing region(US_WEST_2) in SES sample code provide by Amazon, its not working in sample code also. Can you please try once by changing region in sample code. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/SES_FeedbackForm

Comment: The sample app works for me. What's the value of `ses.endpoint` after you assign `[AmazonEndpoints sesEndpoint:US_WEST_2]`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of verifying emails you look on the following issue where you can make it more Production based.

[How can i send mail without verifying the recipients in amazon ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724027/how-can-i-send-mail-without-verifying-the-recipients-in-amazon-ses/48342952#48342952)

This approach is more correct & more appropriate even though you do it for any region.