# How can i send mail without verifying the recipients in amazon ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been trying to send mail with amazon ses and it worked very well for all the verified recipients. But i have a requirement to send mails to un verified recipients now. How to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your SES account is in Sandbox Mode. You need to open a request with AWS to take your SES account out of Sandbox Mode. This is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).

Comment: I am trying to integrate aws ses into an office management software. Where the users can send email to their clients. I have a doubt here. Even though I have moved of sandbox mode. And my domain is also verified. Whenever the user tries to send the mail to their clients, it gives an error email address not verified. Is this because the user and clients email addresses are not verified. Or is there any other reason.

Comment: @YogeshKudikala You haven't moved out of sandbox mode if you are getting that error.

Answer (score 9):

> By default, AWS never provides you full access and needs certain
>   verification(s) to ensure security & remove possibilities of
>   Fraudulent activities or Spam.

These steps will resolve all the issue(s) regarding current scenario in your AWS SES Setup.

1)  Verify “your-domain.com” Domain using the TXT record mentioned in [Verification Tab - SES Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#verified-sender-details:domain:%3Cyour-domain%3E). By doing this you can use any ID in From Address to send emails.

2)  Raise a Case on Amazon Support for Production Access. [SES > Production Access](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest). By doing this you can have the full access of TO addresses and can send emails to anyone.
[image: AWS Support Ticket or Case]

Kindly let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: It's lame that you need to have AWS Support to even open this ticket.  Does my company not give enough money to Amazon?

Comment: @RobertJ It's because they don't want to have any Spams/Phishing attacks going thru the amazon's channels. It's a verification step more than a feature request.

Comment: that's still no excuse to require a paid subscription for another service to use the full functionally of the initial service.  This should really be considered a limit increase, and not an actual support ticket.  Everyone would jump cloud if this was required for all limit increases.

Comment: I am trying to integrate aws ses into an office management software. Where the users can send email to their clients. I have a doubt here. Even though I have moved of sandbox mode. And my domain is also verified. Whenever the user tries to send the mail to their clients, it gives an error email address not verified. Is this because the user and clients email addresses are not verified. Or is there any other reason.

Comment: Check with your AWS Support Contact, If it's moved out of Sandbox mode or not.